# How to do a factory reset when recovery mode, usb debugging and factory reset don't work?

Tags: recovery-mode, bootloader, system-error, malware, bootloader-lock

I have a device called "EXEQ SET": http://www.exeq.ru/produkcija/pristavki/os-android/set.html

It runs Android 4.1.1.

It is spitting out errors like this every other second, making the device almost unusable:

```
The process com.google.process.gapps has stopped

The process 'Google Play Store Services' has stopped

The process 'Launcher' has stopped
```

Here's what I have tried to re-flash the device:

1. I turned off the device, then pressed the key combination to boot into bootloader/recovery mode, which is Home+Power according to "documentation". The power led lights up, but the screen is completely blank and the device doesn't seem to turn on. I have to hold the power button for a few seconds to turn it off from this state.
2. When I go to Developer options menu and turn it on, it immediately switches the developer options menu off. This isn't instantly visibly, I have to re-enter the menu for it to refresh.

   Both `adb devices` and `fastboot devices` commands give empty output when the device is turned on and on all stages of boot.
3. When doing a factory reset from menu, the button simply does nothing.

I suspect this might be because of some malware.

Are there any other ways of doing a factory reset?

Comment: What OS are you using?  Do you have the hardware IDs added to adb_usb.ini?  (Side note, this doesn't sound like malware.)

Comment: @MatthewRead I use Arch Linux. When I connect my phone (nexus) via usb, it shows up in the output of `adb devices`. So I assume this other device should "just work" as well.

Comment: No, generally the Android SDK comes set up to recognize Nexus devices and sometimes major manufacturers; I'd doubt that EXEQ would be included.  Run `lsusb` with your device connected to get the Vendor ID, then follow step 3 [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up).  Then also add that ID (e.g., `0xabcd`) to adb_usb.ini, which is usually located in `~/.android/`.

Comment: Additionally to Matthew's good comment: After adding your vendor to adb_usb.ini you should run adb as root.  `adb kill-server; sudo $(which adb start-server)`

Comment: @MatthewRead Here's the output of lsusb: `Bus 001 Device 009: ID 18d1:8301 Google Inc.`. I added the following `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"` to `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` but the output of `adb devices` is still empty.

Comment: @divided-by-zero Also added `0x18D1` to `.android/adb_usb.ini` and ran `adb kill-server; sudo $(which adb start-server` but the output of `sudo adb devices` is still empty.

Comment: That's very strange.  I assume it must be due to the Developer Options not enabling, as you say.  Are you rooted?  I'm not sure if running the adb daemon (`/sbin/adbd`) manually on the device via a terminal emulator would work.

Comment: Maybe it should be [ATTRS](http://jeromejaglale.com/doc/android/device_with_ubuntu) not ATTR? Something like `SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="8301", MODE="0660", OWNER="yourusername"` Also try combinations of power+volume up and down for recovery because the documentation could be wrong.  Finally, download the [ROM source](http://www.exeq.ru/files/ware/Set-firmware2014.zip) and see what clues might be there. E.g., if it is a uboot bootloader the source should reveal what the keys are to load recovery. Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10817721/507761).

Comment: @fattire Oh wow you are right it's Volumen up + Power button! Docs are wrong indeed. Add it as an answer please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Volume Up + Power to get into Recovery mode.  From there you should be able to perform a factory reset or flash a ROM.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be from fastboot by issuing a 'fastboot erase userdata' command. But booting afterwards might be troublesome because you will have no filesystem on your userdata partition! It is normal that you don't see anything on your screen except the LED when booting into fastboot mode using the key combo.

Just run fastboot as root on your computer (best on a live system with fastboot), then you don't need to mess with the device rules stuff. To me it seems very unlikely that the malware managed to manipulate your bootloader in a way that it still boots the system but does not allow entering fastboot mode.

Please be aware though that most malware cannot be removed by simply doing a factory reset as the factory reset only removes user data, not system stuff. If the malware managed to modify your boot or system partition (which is very likely) you will have to re-flash these partitions back to a stock state. Do you have access to an image of the stock firmware?